# How can I add sorting to HTML table columns that has multiple headers

Tags: javascript, html, css

There are multiple headers in my HTML table . How do I add sorting to this table? My table is shown below.

I would like to add sort only on top header and then it should sort all the columns including the rows in the second and third header.

https://codepen.io/magic12/pen/QWmvpyM

There are multiple headers in my HTML table . How do I add sorting to this table? My table is shown below.

I would like to add sort only on top header and then it should sort all the columns including the rows in the second and third header.

https://codepen.io/magic12/pen/QWmvpyM

HTML:

```
    <p><input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search" title="Searche"></p>
    <table class="table_brdr" id="myTable">
    <tr>
    <th>Column1</th>
    <th><strong>Column2</th>
    <th>Column3</th>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>xyz</td>
    <td>03/30/2017</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td>test12</td>
    <td>https://www.yahoo.com/ </td>
    <td>03/30/2017</td>
    </tr>
      
    <tr>
    <th>Column1</th>
    <th> New Column</th>
    <th>Column3</th>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>abctd <td>
    <td>09/30/2019</td>
    </tr>
      
    <tr>
    <th>Column1</th>
    <th> New Column2</th>
    <th>Column3</th>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>abctd </td>
    <td>06/30/2019</td>
    </tr>
    
    </tbody></table>
```

CSS:

```
table.table_brdr td {
    padding: 8px 10px;
    border: none;
}

table.table_brdr th {
    background-color: #a6a6a6;
    color: black;
}

tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
      background-color#D3D3D3;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 20%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        var allTDs = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");

        for (index = 0; index < allTDs.length; index++) {
            txtValue = allTDs[index].textContent || allTDs[index].innerText;
            if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
                break;
            } else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why not respecting HTML5 syntax and use tags `<tbody>`<thead>` and `<tfoot>` ?

Comment: This table is being published from cms (content management system) and I have no cotrol over it. I was hoping to use Javascript to add sorting.

Comment: change CMS, seen from here the generated table does not respect any existing html syntax!

Comment: On what basis do you want to sort this? Rows based on ascending descending?

Comment: Default Ascending, but should be able to sort descending as well.

Comment: Isthere a way to add thead tags through Javascript?